# Populate Multiple Combo's With An string array

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to populate Several Different ComboBoxes Via a foreach, i have tried to see if it loops but it doesn't i would greatly appreciate any help

#### Code:

```
        private void ItemsList()
        {
            string[] ItemsPlat = new string[468];
            int HexString;
            int[] ItemOffsets =
            {
                0xEBAFC, 0xEBB00, 0xEBB04, 0xEBB08, 0xEBB0C, 0xEBB10,
                0xEBB14, 0xEBB18, 0xEBB1C, 0xEBB20, 0xEBB24, 0xEBB28,
                0xEBB2C, 0xEBB30, 0xEBB34, 0xEBB38, 0xEBB3C, 0xEBB40,
            };
            
            ItemsPlat = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Username\source\repos\ProjectName\ItemsPlat.txt", Encoding.UTF8);//Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "ItemsPlat.txt"
            
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemOffsets.Length; i++) 
            {
                foreach(var Combobox in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>()) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("hello world");
                    Combobox.Items.Add(ItemsPlat[Convert.ToInt16(HexString)]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does happen when you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: Maybe your comboboxes are not in the top layer of the form(`this` refers to the form) but in a container control like Panel or GroupBox. `OfType` does not look into child controls recursively.

Comment: Where are you assigning a value to HexString variable?

Comment: @TimSchmelter This was the problem thank you, however it was Painfully slow (10s) so i opted to use the Items (collection) property in the comboboxes :)